# Unexpected identifier in Nesk/Rialto (Puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, puppeteer

I'm running Puppeteer via Puphpeteer, in one of my Laravel 5.8.35 commands. 
It works perfectly when I run it via the console (e.g. php artisan CommandName). However, when this same command runs via the scheduled cron (via app\Console\Kernel.php), I get the following error:

Nesk\Rialto\Exceptions\Node\FatalException
Unexpected identifier
- the error line is:
`$puppeteer = new Puppeteer;`

A fuller code excerpt is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Nesk\Puphpeteer\Puppeteer;
use Nesk\Rialto\Data\JsFunction;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

class ScrapeRezdy extends Command{
    protected $signature = 'SomeCommand';
    protected $description = 'Command description';
    public function __construct(){parent::__construct();}
    public function handle()    {

        $puppeteer = new Puppeteer;
        $browser = $puppeteer->launch();
    ...
```

It actually worked perfectly previously via the cron on my old server, but on my new AWS server it's having the problem mentioned above. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Do you have differing PHP versions between the successful and failing server? Off the top of my head, I wonder if it would work via `$puppeteer = new Puppeteer();` (with the `()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the node path, which had to be updated - public_html/vendor/nesk/rialto/src/ProcessSupervisor.php
'executable_path' => '/home/master/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/bin/node'